# Why do Google News feeds have such strange structure?

Tags: rss, simplepie

I'm trying to incorporate a google news feed in my website (Using the built-in SimplePie functionality of WordPress).

However, the default feed gets rendered in a strange table structure.  Sure enough, when I inspect the feed XML, I see that Google News has a whole bunch of table html as its 'description' element, complete with embedded styles, etc (See this [example](http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&q=oren%20kessler&cf=all&output=rss))- essentially dictating how the feed must be displayed, and not allowing for any effective css based customization.

This seems really dumb- can anyone help explain what is going on, or at least agree with me that this is just a terrible feed architecture?

Comment: Feeds often include html tags, as many (most?) readers will handle and use them, and that way the RSS provider can have some nice looking output in the reader, as you've guessed.  (I prefer flagging it as CDATA unless it's proper xhtml, as it's not valid xml/rss otherwise).  It's not in the original spirit of RSS perhapts, but the Google feed is just an extreme example of common practice.  As per your problem, does trip_htmltags help (http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/strip_htmltags)?

Comment: @ViennaMike- strip_htmltags is just what I needed! - Please make your comment an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeds often include html tags, as many (most?) readers will handle and use them, and that way the RSS provider can have some nice looking output in the reader, as you've guessed. (I prefer flagging it as CDATA unless it's proper xhtml, as it's not valid xml/rss otherwise). It's not in the original spirit of RSS perhapts, but the Google feed is just an extreme example of common practice. As per your problem, does strip_htmltags help (simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/strip_htmltags)?